# Почему не отрабатывает запрос GET в Indy компонентах RAD STUDIO 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10-berlin

Установлена RadSudio 10.1 Berlin.
Впервые сталкиваюсь с Indy. Не могу понять, что не так.
Никак не хочет отрабатывать код.

Всё на событие на одну кнопку повесил для проверки работы с компонентами.

Выдаётся ошибка в обоих вариантах:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EIdUnknownProtocol with message 'Unknown Protocol'

IdTCPClient1.Connect; - проходит без ошибок.

Get выдаёт ошибку на любой сайт. Что не так?

Первая вариация без особых настроек:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdTCPClient1 : TIdTCPClient;
  IdHTTP1 : TIdHTTP;
  IdCookieManager1 : TIdCookieManager;
begin
  IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  IdCookieManager1 := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  //----
  //Настраиваем компонент.
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;
  IdTCPClient1.Host := 'mail.ru';
  //----
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(IdTCPClient1.Host);
  finally
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    IdCookieManager1.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
    IdTCPClient1.Free;
  end;     
end;
```

Второй вариант - ошибка та же вылетает:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdTCPClient1 : TIdTCPClient;
  IdHTTP1 : TIdHTTP;
  IdCookieManager1 : TIdCookieManager;
begin
  IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  IdCookieManager1 := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdTCPClient1);
  //----
  //Настраиваем компонент.
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
  IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
  IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3';
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 80;
  IdTCPClient1.Host := 'mail.ru';
  //----
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(IdTCPClient1.Host);
  finally
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    IdCookieManager1.Free;
    IdHTTP1.Free;
    IdTCPClient1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Когда ставлю 'http://mail.ru' - то уже на IdTCPClient1.Connect; вылетает ошибка:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 11001 Host not found.

Comment: Нужно использовать именно Indy компоненты.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы попытаетесь в браузере зайти по `http://mail.ru/`, вы будете перенаправлены на `https://mail.ru/` (получите ответ сервера [HTTP/1.1 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)).

Поскольку в Indy вы указали автоматически следовать редиректам, то он, получив ответ 302, сделает новый запрос и попытается зайти на `https` версию сайта. НО для установки защищённого соединения, в Indy вы должны указать обработчик защищённого соединения, т.к. по умолчанию, Indy умеет обрабатывать только незащищённые http соединения. Делается это примерно вот так:

```
uses
  IdHTTP,
  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdCookieManager;

procedure IndyTest;
var
  VResp: string;
  VIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  VIdCookieManager: TIdCookieManager;
  VIdIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  VIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    VIdCookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
    VIdIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    try
      VIdHTTP.IOHandler := VIdIOHandler;
      VIdHTTP.CookieManager := VIdCookieManager;
      VIdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
      VIdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;

      VResp := VIdHTTP.Get('http://mail.ru/');
    finally
      VIdCookieManager.Free;
      VIdIOHandler.Free;
    end;
  finally
    VIdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

При этом, у вас должен быть установлен [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), либо рядом с `exe` должны лежать 2 библиотеки: `libeay32.dll` и `ssleay32.dll`.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло и с SSL заработало!

Comment: @Programmer тогда отметьте ответ как решение.

Comment: Пример отличного ответа.